# conditional functionality for ie7 in javascript

Tags: javascript

There is anyway to find write a function that should work only for iexplorer7 and not for the other browser using javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.appCodeName == "browsername")
    {
       *your code*
    }
</script>
```

it work for other browsers too

Answer (score 0):

You could try conditional comments

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script>
(function () {
    //...
})();
</script>
<![endif]-->
```